InTune uninstall script in "error" - Where can I see what the error is to troubleshoot it?
Following up on another question here , I'm trying to uninstall Firefox on managed PCs via an InTune script. Script is pasted below for reference.
Script is marked as being in "error", but I can't find a way to get detailed error information, allowing me to troubleshoot. Where can I get details about what went wrong (in InTune, or on the managed PC itself?)?
FYI I use InTune for Education, but can look in InTune if necessary.
Thanks!
$SEARCH = 'Mozilla Firefo$'

$INSTALLED = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, UninstallString

$INSTALLED += Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, UninstallString

$RESULT = $INSTALLED | ?{ $_.DisplayName -ne $null } | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match $SEARCH }

if ($RESULT.uninstallstring -like "msiexec*") {
$ARGYY=(($RESULT.UninstallString -split ' ')[1] -replace '/I','/X ') + ' /qn'
Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $ARGYY -Wait
} else {
$UNINSTALL_COMMAND=(($RESULT.UninstallString -split '\"')[1])
$UNINSTALL_ARGS=(($RESULT.UninstallString -split '\"')[2]) + ' --force-uninstall'
Start-Process $UNINSTALL_COMMAND -ArgumentList $UNINSTALL_ARGS -Wait}

